# How do I turn off the sql server by default on startup?

Tags: mysql

As soon as I turn on my system and run the command :

```
service mysql status
```

It shows that the service has been activated since the PC was turned on, I want it to be off my default and when I want to, I should be able to activate it by :

```
service mysql start
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu 16.04 and newer use

```
systemctl disable mysqld.service
```

Notice the difference: `stop` to stop the running service and `disable` to disable autostart.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 is with `systemctl disable mysql`, I did not test your command. Anyway, is true about the difference between _running service_ and _disable autostart_